# Matlab - comparing multidimensional double/float arrays (isequal)

Tags: matlab, double, assert

Assume I have two matrices A,B of values of type double.

What's the Matlab way of doing isequal(A,B) with some element-wise sensitivity (epsilon)?

E.g. all elements in A-B are smaller than some value (for instance 1e-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
all( abs( A(:) - B(:) ) < tol )
```